# Why is this expression not a constant expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

The expression `b` in this code shall be a *core constant expression*

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int a = 10;
    const int &b = a;
    constexpr int c = b; // Here
    return 0;
}
```

since the standard says (8.20, paragraph 2 [expr.const] in [n4700](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4700.pdf))

> An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of
> `e` would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - ...
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (7.1) unless it is applied to
>
>   - ...
>   - **a non-volatile glvalue** that refers to **a non-volatile object defined with constexpr**, or that refers to a non-mutable subobject of such an object, or

First, the expression `b` in the above code is an lvalue (which is also a glvalue) since it's a reference, thereby being a variable (8.1.4.1, paragraph 1
[expr.prim.id.unqual]):

> The expression is an lvalue if the entity is a function,
> **variable**, or data member and a prvalue otherwise; it is a bit-field if the identifier designates a bit-field (11.5).

Second, the object the variable `b` denotes is `a`, and it's declared with `constexpr`. However, GCC complains:

```
./hello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./hello.cpp:6:20: error: the value of ‘b’ is not usable in a constant expression
  constexpr int c = b;
                    ^
./hello.cpp:5:13: note: ‘b’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
  const int &b = a;
```

As far as I can tell, **a reference is not an object,** so the above bullet apparently suggests that `a` shall be declared with `constexpr`. Am I missing something?

The reason why I don't agree with GCC is that GCC sees `b` as an object, thereby requiring it to be declared with `constexpr`. However, `b` is not an object!

Comment: Clang agrees with GCC. But I think I agree with you, this is a defect in either the standard or the compilers. Also of note is that MSVC accepts the code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One of the rules for core constant expressions is that we [can't evaluate](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.11):

> an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
> - it is initialized with a constant expression or
> - its lifetime began within the evaluation of e;

`b` is an *id-expression* that refers to a variable of reference type with preceding initialization. However, it is initialized from `a`. Is `a` a constant expression? From [[expr.const]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6):

> A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints: [... ]
>
> An entity is a *permitted result of a constant expression* if it is an object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or it is a function.

`a` is a glvalue core constant expression (it doesn't hit any of the restrictions in expr.const/2), however it is *not* an object with static storage duration. Nor is it a function.

Hence, `a` is not a constant expression. And `b`, as a result, isn't initialized from a constant expression and so can't be used in a core constant expression. And thus `c`'s initialization is ill-formed as not being a constant expression. Declare `a` as a `static constexpr int`, and both GCC and Clang accept the program.

C++, you magical beast.

Comment: `b` is initialized with a glvalue, and **`a` as a glvalue** is not a constant expression.

Comment: indeed, note that clang refuses to compile also "constexpr int const& b = a;" saying "reference to 'a' is not a constant expression"...

Comment: Maybe because `a` is a local variable, so the underlying pointer would change?

Comment: Would you guys pinpoint the specific bullet hindering `a` from being a constant expression? I don't think that there is one...

Comment: [\[expr.const\]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6): "A _constant expression_ is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression[...]. An entity is a _permitted result of a constant expression_ if it is an object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or it is a function."

Comment: ... `a` is not "an object with static storage duration" or "a temporary object" or "a function".

Comment: @SebastianRedl, yes, and the same reasoning seems to allow concluding that b is *not* initialized with a constant expression ... hence neutralizing Barry's quote ?

Comment: Can we suggest that a glvalue expression can also be considered as a prvalue expression, since the conversion is possible?

Comment: With the modification that you mentioned, clang 3.8.0 indeed accepts it... It's weird that gcc still rejects it. Which version did you use?

Comment: Well, saying that "`a` is not a constant expression" would be incorrect. `a` is a constant expression in prvalue contexts. You can use `a` to declare bit-field width, for example. But apparently the original comment made by @cpplearner is the right way to see it: it is not a constant expression *in glvalue contexts* specifically.

Comment: @AnT There, I disagree. Bit-field asks for an "integral constant expression" which is not a subset of "constant expression" but rather "an expression of integral [...] type, implicitly converted to a prvalue, where the converted expression is a core constant expression." Different requirement.