# Reference initialization and constant expressions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

As a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47908885/2069064), gcc and clang both consider this program ill-formed:

```
int main() {
    const int& ri = 0;
    constexpr int i = ri;
}
```

The error is about the value of `ri` being unusable in a constant expression. `0` is certainly a core constant expression, and as a prvalue core constant expression seems to satisfy [these constraints](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6) (trivially, since `int` isn't of class, pointer, or array type). So shouldn't `ri` satisfy [this criteria](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.11)?

The same is true if I use a prvalue literal of class type:

```
struct X { };
int main() {
    const X& rx = X{};
    constexpr X x = rx;
}
```

Comment: An object can't be of class, pointer and array type simultaneously. No object can satisfy all the constraints. It must satisfy the appropriate one. An object of type `int` satisfies neither. So no, `ri` wouldn't apply.

Comment: D'oh. Thank you for making me aware that I misread [\[expr.const\]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6.sentence-2). It should read "an object with static storage duration that is (either not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints)", not "(an object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary object) or (is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints)".

Comment: @StoryTeller The constraint `P -> Q` is satisfied by `!P`.

Comment: @Barry - I'm reading it more like `P1 || P2 || P3`. Where it just so happens all three are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @StoryTeller They're not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Barry - The bullets are not mutually exclusive? How so? Only one can apply to any type, at most.

Comment: @StoryTeller If the object is of class type, we check both [non-static data members of reference type](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6.1) and [subobjects, recursively](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6.3)

Comment: @Barry - Checking the members recursively doesn't mean we apply more than one bullet to the super-object itself. But w/e, that's beside the point. Even if, for the sake of argument, a type satisfies more then one bullet, the satisfaction of *at least* one is still required. That paragraph is an only-if relationship. Which seems to suffer from some natural language pitfalls.

Comment: The reference is initialized with the glvalue result of the temporary materialization conversion applied to the prvalue `0` adjusted to type `const int`. You can't ignore the conversions and consider only the syntactic form of the initializer.

Comment: @StoryTeller What? We have to satisfy **all** the bullets, all "the following constraints." There is no "or", there is no "at least one".

Answer (score 6):

In this statement:

```
const int& ri = 0;
```

`0` is a prvalue, but `ri` isn't initialized from that prvalue. The prvalue first undergoes a [temporary materialization conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#ref-5.2.1) and the reference is bound to the resulting glvalue. Since `ri` is bound to this materialized glvalue, and not directly to the prvalue like you (I) suspected, the relevant restrictions are not the prvalue core constant expression restrictions (which `0` does satisfy) but rather the *glvalue* core constant expression restrictions - that the entity be a [*permitted result of a constant expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6). That restriction, spelled with slightly improved clarity, is:

> either an object with static storage duration that is:
>
> - not a temporary object, or
> - a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints,
>
> or it is a function.

Our glvalue *is* a temporary object whose value satisfies "the above constraints" ("above" here referring to the prvalue core constant restrictions, which `int` trivially satisfies), but it does *not* have static storage duration.

Not having static storage duration → the entity is not a permitted result of a constant expression → the glvalue expression not a constant expression →  `ri` wasn't initialized with a constant expression → `ri` can't be used in a core constant expression → the declaration of `i` is ill-formed.

The same argument holds for appropriate class types as well.

Comment: What does it mean for a temporary have static storage duration?

Comment: @PasserBy something like  `static int const &r = 0;` The reference `r` is bound to materialized temporary of a const-qualified type having static storage duration holding the value `0`.

Comment: @John See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945299/what-is-a-temporary-object-with-static-storage-duration

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, 2.11 states that a *core constant expression* must not evaluate to:

> - an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and
>     either
>
>   - it is initialized with a constant expression or

And further expr.const#6:

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression
>   that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant
>   expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression
>   whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> ...
>
> An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an
>   object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary
>   object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above
>   constraints, or it is a function.

From my reading of this, it means that the RHS of `const X& r =` (substitute X for some type) must either be an object with static storage duration **or** a temporary object that meets the above criteria. Since an `int` does not fit either an object of class type, a pointer type or class/array type, it does not qualify.